# Difference between panTo and setCenter

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Where is the difference between the `panTo` and `setCenter` functions in the [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)? Both seem to change the center of the map to the given point.

Comment: panTo may set the center with an animation

Answer (score 5):

According to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions):

panTo:

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
>   less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
>   smoothly animated.

setCenter simply changes the center of the map.